# Css3 : Having a background for 300ms?

Tags: css, css-transitions

Currently I'm adding a class to a div to change it's background and then removing it with a timeout after 300ms (This is for user feedback purposes).

I was asking myself : Is it possible to do the same thing with pure CSS3 (transitions ?) or not ?

NB: The best would be something compatible on Android 2.3+ (I know iOS has better compatibilites)

Edit: I should have added that I wanted to do that on pseudo-class active. It seems that transition/animations stop instantly when the div is not active anymore !

Comment: yes, but with animations

Comment: Well I need to target Android 2.3+ (among others). Can I still do it or I'll need to stick to the JS method ?

Comment: Why don't you try it? http://jsfiddle.net/kq3XC/ caniuse mentions buggy behavior in Android 2.3, so the best is to try it and see

Comment: You can't detect pseudo-classes in js. Either make it a sub element instead or use a CSS animation